# Problem installing ipykernel on visual studio code with pip for jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, jupyter

I'm trying to open a document using Jupyter on Visual Studio Code but when I try launching the first request I'm asked to install ipykernel. And when I do that (using 'pip install ipykernel' or 'pip install ipykernel -U --user --force-reinstall') after some steps an error message telling me that the file _implementation.pyi in directory Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\jedi\third_party\typeshed\third_party\2and3\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\ssl_match_hostname does not exist.

Can you help me, I've already try uninstalling and reinstalling python, Jupyter, VSC, and it seems that nothing is working...

I've already try uninstalling and reinstalling python, Jupyter, VSC, and it seems that nothing is working...